# Is the JVM a part of an OS or package?

Tags: java, jvm

I know Java Virtual Machine is used to run a java program independent of the OS.But can anyone tell me if JVM is the part of OS or a package.

Comment: Which one would be _the_ OS?

Comment: It's not a part of OS on Windows, OSX, Ubuntu, Debian, Redhat... But it's a part of Android OS for example

Comment: Some Linux distributions include OpenJDK by default

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your definition of OS, your definition of package and your actual OS.

Some OS vendors ship a JRE or JDK as part of their OS install in eigter core or extended sets. They all ship it as packages. This includes AIX, Solaris and some of the commercial Linux distributions.

However, without knowning your background it is safe to say it would be a stretch to consider Java to be a part of the OS itself. The one exception would be Android (however it is debatable if the Android VMs can safely be called Java :)

(Not talking about embedded and card os here).